# Docker (Postgres image): authentication problem

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, docker

I am running a Django project at the moment and I have an error when I try to use the command python manage.py migrate.

I have a docker image called explore_hub.

When I run python manage.py migrate I have the followin error:

System check identified some issues:

System check identified some issues:

```
WARNINGS:
?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory 'D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\explore_hub\static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 270, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: No such host is known.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\explore_hub\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\explore_hub\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 117, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 330, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 306, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 288, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 270, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\2xProjects\Python\ExploreHub\.dj-env\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: No such host is known.
```

I have zero clues why. I tried and I can't figure it out with what I saw on the internet for now. I would appreciate a detailed explanation on why this is happening... I just don't get it.

Here are some important files that might help you:

Docker logs for the explore_hub container:

```
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | This user must also own the server process.
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | 
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | 
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | Data page checksums are disabled.
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | 
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | creating subdirectories ... ok
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | selecting default max_connections ... 100
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | creating configuration files ... ok
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | running bootstrap script ... ok
2023-11-17 09:50:54 explore_hub-db-1  | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | initdb: hint: You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | syncing data to disk ... ok
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | Success. You can now start the database server using:
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | waiting for server to start....2023-11-17 07:50:55.165 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 2023-11-17 07:50:55.168 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 2023-11-17 07:50:55.179 UTC [51] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-11-17 07:50:54 UTC
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 2023-11-17 07:50:55.184 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  |  done
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | server started
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | CREATE DATABASE
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | waiting for server to shut down...2023-11-17 07:50:55.340 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | .2023-11-17 07:50:55.343 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 2023-11-17 07:50:55.344 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 54) exited with exit code 1
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 2023-11-17 07:50:55.344 UTC [49] LOG:  shutting down
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 2023-11-17 07:50:55.348 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 2023-11-17 07:50:55.458 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 923 buffers (5.6%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.014 s, sync=0.086 s, total=0.114 s; sync files=301, longest=0.019 s, average=0.001 s; distance=4257 kB, estimate=4257 kB; lsn=0/1913070, redo lsn=0/1913070
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 2023-11-17 07:50:55.462 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  |  done
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | server stopped
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 2023-11-17 07:50:55.559 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 2023-11-17 07:50:55.559 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 2023-11-17 07:50:55.559 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 2023-11-17 07:50:55.564 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 2023-11-17 07:50:55.572 UTC [64] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-11-17 07:50:55 UTC
2023-11-17 09:50:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 2023-11-17 07:50:55.578 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-11-17 09:55:55 explore_hub-db-1  | 2023-11-17 07:55:55.671 UTC [62] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2023-11-17 09:55:59 explore_hub-db-1  | 2023-11-17 07:55:59.905 UTC [62] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 45 buffers (0.3%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=4.214 s, sync=0.009 s, total=4.234 s; sync files=12, longest=0.004 s, average=0.001 s; distance=261 kB, estimate=261 kB; lsn=0/19544A8, redo lsn=0/1954470
```

My docker-compose.yml file that I used to create the image:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: explorehubdb
      POSTGRES_USER: suadmin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: suadmin321
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

The settings.py file from Django:

```
"""
Django settings for explore_hub project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-_&capv+qh$guh)%!-voyb9nq#4ssai9jq8*=-6#n^j2_0!+gnv'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'your_django_container_ip']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_bootstrap5',
    'header',
    'e_h_login_page',
    'e_h_main_page'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'explore_hub.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates'
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'explore_hub.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'explorehubdb',
        'USER': 'suadmin',
        'PASSWORD': 'suadmin321',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static'
]


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

My requirements.txt file:

```
asgiref==3.7.2
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
Django==4.2.7
django-bootstrap5==23.3
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
soupsieve==2.5
sqlparse==0.4.4
tzdata==2023.3
```

Thank you for your time and help!

PS: If you need more details I will gladly edit and provide all the details that I can offer. Ask me and it shall be done :)

EDIT: Because of the suggestion of Marin now I solved the previous error but I receive a new one. The issue has been updated to reflect the new problem.

Comment: this is not how you should act. If marins answer was correct, you should approve it and upvote it and post another question for next one.   Now noone knows what marin solved and it will not be heplful for anyone, people will downvote Marins answer.

Comment: Your compose file is not putting the container into a network, so I wouldn't expect it to be addressable by using the container name as the host name.

Comment: @ElvinJafarov Sorry, I did not know. I upvoted his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put this in settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'explorehubdb',
        'USER': 'suadmin',
        'PASSWORD': 'suadmin321',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I updated the post because now I get a new error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: No such host is known.

Comment: add 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'

Comment: Is there a problem with my windows? I receive the same error even after the modified ENGINE